# why this code <center> any thing</center> is rendered correctly in HTML5 though the <center> tag is not available in it?

Tags: html, tags, center, doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

      <center> any text </center>

    </body>

</html>
```

---

I thought that the  content wouldn't rendered in the center of the page because it is not a part of html5 , as it is deprecated , but it doesn't. why that occurred in all the browsers I used.

Comment: Deprecated means that it's not recommended, not that it has has been removed.

Comment: Browsers like to stay backwards compatible. It'd be unfortunate if old websites all of a sudden stopped working.

Comment: @takendarkk 
this snippet :
" Deprecated Tags means elements are not available in HTML5 anymore"
is taken from tutorialsPoint website https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_deprecated_tags.htm
And this is another website https://benohead.com/blog/2013/09/09/html5-removed-elements-tags-and-attributes/

Comment: @MoFayyad - There's a lot of poorly described info about HTML on the web, often in places that ought to know better. The HTML5 Standard does not _deprecate_ anything at all. It says that the center element is [_obsolete_ and _non-conforming_](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features). Which means that it _requires_ that web authors do not use it. But it also describes exactly [how browsers should apply styling to the center element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#flow-content-3:center)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe browsers still support HTML4 and the `<center>` tag was used in HTML4 to center the text.

Comment: [<center>](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-CENTER) was deprecated in HTML4 as well.

Comment: You can refer here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

Comment: w3schools is a well known error-filled resource, and your link confirms that once again. For completeness, <center> was introduced by Netscape in [Extensions to HTML 2.0](http://web.archive.org/web/19981205171938/http://home.mcom.com/assist/net_sites/html_extensions.html) and was valid in [HTML 3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html32-20180315/#center). It was deprecated in HTML 4.01 (see my link above), and obsoleted in HTML5.